# ManyToOne with where clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have some logically deleted records (ie `active=false`) which are causing problems with my `@ManyToOne` mapping since more than one result is being returned by the join column.

I need to only include records where `active=true` which I thought I could achieve by:

```
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "site_id", referencedColumnName = "site_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "active=true")
private Site site;
```

However, it seems like the `WhereJoinTable` is not being used by hibernate (perhaps its only valid for `OneToMany`?) since the `active=true` does not show up in the generated SQL (logs) and the problem persists.

Is it possible to include a where clause for the join of a `ManyToOne` and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@WhereJoinTable is not supported with @ManyToOne. There is bug [HHH-4335](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4335) about subject open since five years. I am not aware about any workaround, except using view (in the case of read-only access) as mentioned in bug report.

Comment: is it possible to re-map the same table and put a filter on the mapping, ie so i have a read only `ActiveSite` entity?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But as expected connection between instances of ActiveSite and Site is then unknown to Hibernate. So changes made to corresponding Site are mirrored to ActiveSite only when it is read (or refreshed) from database.

Comment: yep that would be acceptable in this case, however i'm trying to use the `@Where(clause="active=true")` on my `@Entity` and hibernate is converting it to `site0_.active=site0_.true` .. if you can help me solve that one i'll give you the tick (since you are right in your answer..) thanks for the help!

Comment: never mind, "active" (without "=true") works fine. thanks again.

Comment: Dear #pstanton How you used @where, could you please past here.

Answer (score 1):

[@JoinColumnOrFormula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-JoinColumnOrFormula) anotation is a suitable workaround

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, please use comments for discussions and not-answer-related posts

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is add @where annotation in the top of the class, see the next example:

```
@Where(clause = "state_.idCity=0")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="city", schema="catalog")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "default_gen", sequenceName = "IDSERIEINVALIDO", allocationSize = 1)
public class Citye implements Serializable{
        
    @Id 
    private Long id;
}
```